# Get all Nodes and Relationships with Propperties outgoing from one StartNode

Tags: c#, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm completely new in the GraphDatabase world and also in writing Cypher Statements.

I have a project, where I want to store wiring diagram information inside a graph database (Neo4J). There are different types of Nodes like f.e. WiringDiagram [WD] Node (will be my start node in many cases) and regarding this WD Node all components like fuseboxes, ICU's or sensors are linked via relationships. Plugs also can contain Pins, and Pins are connected via Connectionlines.

The first version is already stored in the Neo4j Database, have a look at the following image.

[image: Graphdatabase Schema]
Now I have a question which way is best to post-process this data. I want the data extracted for one specific wiring Diagram.
So if I would say I want all information about WiringDiagram with ID 123, I should get all components, Pins and Connectenlines which are there. How should the Cypher look like here?
I want the data best in C# Data models (if possible). Because afterwards I want to try to generate an SVG out of the data.

As you can see in the image, the cypher statement looks currently like this. "MATCH (w:WiringDiagram)<-[r:partOf]-(n)-[*2..]-(l) RETURN * LIMIT 50" But with this statement I get strange results in my C# Project...

I would be happy about any help. I'm also open to go forward with another programming language if it fits better for this approach. Happy to hear any suggestions

Comment: when you run your cypher query in neo4j browser, does it gives you the expected result? Can you share your C# code and the error(s) you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I found an APOC function which currently does what I want to.
Get All nodes after the searched one, and give the complete subgroup with relationships back.
Looks currently good.
Any suggestion how to store this data back in data models in C#? (whats best way?)

```
 var result = tx.Run($@"MATCH (p:WiringDiagram {{wiringid:1}})
                        CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(p, {{
                             relationshipFilter: 
                             ""partOf|has_pin|connectedWith"",
                             filterStartNode:false,
                             minLevel: 0,
                             maxLevel: 10
                            }})
                          YIELD nodes, relationships
                         RETURN nodes, relationships;");
```

And after that I've got two lists, one with all the nodes, and one with all relationships with start/endnode id

[image]